# Loop and print element of list using apply in R

Tags: r, list, apply, purrr

I could loop each element from list using for loop:

```
data <- list("Hello", c("USA", "Red", "100"), c("India", "Blue", "76"))
for(i in data){
  print(i)}
```

Result:

```
[1] "Hello"
[1] "USA" "Red" "100"
[1] "India" "Blue"  "76"
```

I wonder what's the equivalent method using `apply` from base R or other functions in `purrr` package?

Comment: For side effects, use the `walk` family. Otherwise, the `map` family is usually your go-to choice.

Comment: My objective is to use `year_months <- c('2021-12', '2021-11', '2021-10')` for `lapply(dfs, customized_func)`, and `dfs` is a list of dataframes, and I need to use `2021-12` for `dfs[[1]]`, `2021-11` for `dfs[[2]]`, etc.

Comment: Check `mapply` in base R. @ahbon

Comment: It was used for to make this code, I updated my attempt to write functions, could you please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70772151/convert-chunk-of-code-to-functions-in-order-to-apply-with-flexibility-to-multi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `purrr`, you can use `walk`:

```
library(purrr)
walk(data, print)

[1] "Hello"
[1] "USA" "Red" "100"
[1] "India" "Blue"  "76"
```

Answer (score 1):

Piping to invisible() will avoid showing the resulting list and give just the print side effect.

```
lapply(data, print) |> invisible()
[1] "Hello"
[1] "USA" "Red" "100"
[1] "India" "Blue"  "76"
```

Comment: Thanks, what the name of the operator `|>` in R? I haven't seen this.

Comment: It's the new (as of R 4.1) native pipe.  It works similarly to %>% in the magrittr package, but without the dot.